# Sporadic zombie NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a timer in a UIViewController:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) int m_remaining_time;
...
@end
```

In .m file:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
{
    NSTimer *m_timer;
}
```

The timer starts on viewDidAppear()

```
m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(decrementSpin) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The method decrementSpin simply decrements the counter and prints a log:

```
- (void)decrementSpin
{
    self.m_remaining_time--;

    if(self.m_remaining_time > 0) {
        NSLog(@"[TIMER] >> %d", self.m_remaining_time);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"[TIMER] >> Time finished!");
        [m_timer invalidate];
        m_timer = nil;
    }
}
```

I destroy the timer in every case the ViewController will close:
In appDidEnterInBackground, viewDidDisappear, when a button that closes the view has been pushed (goind to next view for ex)

The problem is that, in some cases, I have seen in the simulator the log [TIMER] >> %d that keeps printing even after I closed the view.

It is not always the case, but sometimes it keeps counting.

Any clues ?

Edit:

@skaak, I do the following code in appDidEnterInBackground, viewDidDisappear:

```
if(m_timer) {
    [m_timer invalidate];
    m_timer = nil;
}
```

Then when the player pushes the "Next" and "Home" buttons.
For example the case of "Home" button:

```
-(IBAction)homeButtonPressed:(id)sender{
if(m_timer) {
    [m_timer invalidate];
    m_timer = nil;
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];


InitScreenViewController* initVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"initScreenViewController"];
UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:initVc];
[navVC setNavigationBarHidden:true];
[UIView transitionWithView:[AppDelegate getShareInstance].window duration:0.1f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    [AppDelegate getShareInstance].window.rootViewController = navVC;
}completion:nil];
}
```

Edit #2:

I added the following flag:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isCurrentlyViewShowed;
```

Which is set on viewDidAppear (along with your suggestion):

```
self.isCurrentlyViewShowed = TRUE;
if(m_timer) {
    [m_timer invalidate];
    m_timer = nil;
}
m_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(decrementSpin) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then, it is set to off everytime the view is closed:

```
if(m_timer) {
    [m_timer invalidate];
    m_timer = nil;
}
self.isCurrentlyViewShowed = FALSE;
```

And finally, on decrementSpin:

```
if(self.isCurrentlyViewShowed == FALSE){
    if(m_timer) {
        [m_timer invalidate];
        m_timer = nil;
    }
}

self.m_remaining_time--;  

if(self.m_remaining_time > 0) {
    NSLog(@"[TIMER] (%p)>> %d (FLAG: %d)", m_timer, self.m_remaining_time, self.isCurrentlyViewShowed);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"[TIMER] (%p)>> Time finished (FLAG: %d)", m_timer, self.isCurrentlyViewShowes);
    [m_timer invalidate];
    m_timer = nil;
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

I did repeated the test like 100 times and I managed to reproduce it once!
I left this view, and I saw on the log the line:

[TIMER] (0x2818ecfc0)>> 58 (FLAG: 1)
[TIMER] (0x2818ecfc0)>> 57 (FLAG: 1)
...

It means that somehow the View object is re-initialized ? I don't get it..

Comment: I've debugged things like that by logging the `m_timer` address after each creation and invalidate to see what code path leaves more than one running.

Comment: Show how you stop the timer when you go to next page. Are you sure you covered all angles? You could also use block in stead of message when timer fires and there check for a nil self e.g. to cover a lot (not all) of the cases.

Comment: @skaak I have edited the initial question. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure - need to look at it all. But here is an idea. I'll post it as code ..

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, and need the whole code to try and isolate it. But here is an idea that might help. In fact, I think you need to do it like this anyhow. Change your `viewDidAppear` to something like below.

```
- viewDidAppear
{
  if ( ! m_timer )
  {
    m_timer = ...
  }
}
```

or, depending on the logic, to

```
- viewDidAppear
{
  if ( m_timer )
  {
    [m_timer invalidate];
    m_timer = nil;
  }
  m_timer = ...
}
```

In either case you will be sure you have only one timer running at a time which may be your problem.

Comment: interesting the idea that the problem is not that the timer is not stoped, but that a second one is fired. I will test it and let you know.
Another idea maybe is to use a flag, which will be set to on viewDidAppear and off on viewDidDisappear indicating that the view is currently showed. That way, inside decrementSpin, if the flag is off -? invalidate the timer. If on -> do as before.
Maybe use both ideas ?

Comment: Yes - depends on game logic but sounds like you'd need both. This should work on iOS but e.g. in WatchOS there is no symmetry between viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear. Even in iOS you can e.g. have an alert pop up that destroys the sequence you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem was reproduced. Please check part edit #2 from initial question

Comment: Ok - do you use popovers at all? Then viewWillAppear/Disappear is not called. But to fix it I will have to see all of the code as I suspect you've missed one or there is some inbalance between adding and removing the timer.

Comment: How can I share the code of this ViewController ? it is too big. Do you know a good way ?